# Extract documents repository from Liferay

Tags: liferay

**Current situation:**

An instance of Liferay server is used as a Document Management System in an application. It saves the documents in 2 parts:

1. Documents metadata (stored in the database)
2. Physical documents (stored in the file system) with no file extension, file metadata, different file name, etc...

Liferay combines the 2 parts to provide access to the stored documents.

**Required:**

Extract a copy of the whole document repository to be accessed from file system without the need to use Liferay to read them.

The ideal output would be the physical documents with their names and file extensions.

Answer (score 4):

depends on what you want to do with it: In the doclib you find a link "Access from Desktop". Connect to that URL with your file explorer - it's a webdav access URL to your document library.

Alternatively use Liferay Sync

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there another way to access the documents in a read-only mode?

Comment: Same options, use a user account that doesn't have write access to the documents

Comment: I understand. But in my case, I can not create new users with different roles. I want to export the documents in a readable format to be accessible without the need of Liferay.

Comment: Once? All the time? There's nothing built in to constantly do this, but you can use these mechanisms or the api to implement the feature yourself. Or just use file copy of the files that you get with the mechanisms above

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using windows
 1. Goto My Network places.
 2. Click Add network Places and select choose another network location.
 3. Paste the webdav link in "Internet or Network Address". Click next
 4. Use default username and password as "admin" and "admin"
    respectively.
 5. Name the network place eg.. Liferay Documents and click finish
 6. you can access your documents offline.

youtube link [Offline Liferay Document Access](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8--xbnIydo)

Comment: Thanks! This allows full control over the documents. Is there a way to access the documents in a read-only mode?

Comment: Or ideally export the documents in a readable format to be accessible without the need of Liferay.

Comment: make a copy of the network place folder and set permission as  readony to the fresh copy. There is no built in service to do this.